# Why does Roland give away his exemplar of "Insomnia"?

Tags: the-dark-tower, insomnia

When visiting the Tet Corporation in [*The Dark Tower VII: The Dark Tower*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Tower_VII:_The_Dark_Tower) one of the presents Roland gets from them is an exemplar of Stephen King's [*Insomnia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insomnia_(novel)), thinking it would be helpful for his endeavours. However, after first planning to have Susannah read it to him on their journey, he then decides to give it to Irene Tassenbaum instead, apparently in a fit of ka, thinking it might rather be somehow dangerous to have it.

> He  looked at her a moment longer,  consulted the  workings  of his  own  inner  instincts—hunch-think—and came to a decision. From the bag containing the Orizas, he took the envelope containing the bulky book .  .  . the one Susannah would  never  read  to  him  on  the  trail,  after  all.  He  put  it  in Irene's hands.
>
> ... "It feels tricksy to me. [...] It feels .  .  .  thin."  He  was  thinking  of Eyebolt Canyon,  in Mejis.
>
> ... With the book out of his hands, he felt somehow lighter.  Freer. *Safer*.  He  drew her  fully into  his  arms  and  hugged  her.  Irene
> Tassenbaum  returned his strength with her  own.

It remains unclear, though, in which way this was a good idea (*if* it was anyway, but ka-induced decisions are usually the right ones). **Do we know (or are we able to reason at least) in which way *Insomnia* or any information gained therefrom would have been a hindrance (or even danger) to Roland's further journey?** Or was it ultimately irrelevant and Roland's decision wasn't so much ka than just a mood of the moment? Or is this all just more of a whatever-natured meta commentary of King on his book and its relevance as a work?

Assuming this is actually the version of *Insomnia* available to us in the real world (which we don't really have a reason to doubt), this might very well depend on the question if there even *was* anything of relevance in there for the further story to begin with (beyond what Nancy/Marian have already told him in their short rundown). Unfortunately, though, I read this ages ago and before even knowing anything about the *Dark Tower* series. So someone having read it more under that lense explicitly might give more insights there. I first considered asking that as a separate question, but it feels quite relevant on the way to answering this one.